# SmartTarget Deployment Web Service - XML deployed into root directory?

Tags: tridion, smarttarget

I've setup SmartTarget on a separate server and got the SmartTarget Deployment Web Service working so when content is published from Tridion, instead of dropping the XML content generated on the local file system it sends it via the web service to the server where Fredhopper is installed. All good so far...

The problem I have is the deployed XML files are being dropped in Fredhoppers root directory C:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS and not the directory where XML files are loaded from (C:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS\data\xml\incoming\batch)! The only place I've found in configuration for specifying the correct pickup directory is in the SmartTargetDeploymentWebService.properties file in SmartTargetDeploymentWebService.war, but this is setup correctly to point at C:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS\data\xml\incoming\batch

Anyone know what might be causing this? I might just be being stupid so hopefully someone with some experience will be able to point me in the right direction ;)

UPDATE: Spotted this in the logs for when the deployment service first loads:

```
2012-07-19 12:56:05,909 ERROR SmartTargetDeployment - Unable to load configuration for fredhopper.location
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
at com.tridion.smarttarget.web.SmartTargetDeployment.<init>(SmartTargetDeployment.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_23]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [na:1.6.0_23]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [na:1.6.0_23]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [na:1.6.0_23]
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355) [na:1.6.0_23]
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308) [na:1.6.0_23]
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver.createNewInstance(InstanceResolver.java:215) [webservices-rt-1.4.jar:1.0]
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver.createDefault(InstanceResolver.java:180) [webservices-rt-1.4.jar:1.0]
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:124) [webservices-rt-1.4.jar:1.0]
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:467) [webservices-rt-1.4.jar:1.0]
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:253) [webservices-rt-1.4.jar:1.0]
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147) [webservices-rt-1.4.jar:1.0]
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:108) [webservices-rt-1.4.jar:1.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3669) [tmp6105104870192773276catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4104) [tmp6105104870192773276catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:759) [tmp6105104870192773276catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:739) [tmp6105104870192773276catalina.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:524) [tmp6105104870192773276catalina.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you check the location specified in  WEB-INF/classes/SmartTargetDeploymentWebService_conf.xml?

According to the documentation, that's where the location should be set.

Comment: Ah, think I've found my problem. Thanks Nuno, I've looked at the file and that's set to C:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS\data\xml\incoming\batch, but looking in the logs I've spotted the error message (posted above), looks like it's having an issue reading the configuration. I'll get my thinking cap on...thanks anyway!

Comment: Think this is actually just a problem with the server/container i'm using, tried another instance of apache and works fine

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you find null reference exceptions in the realm of XML configuration files, it's helpful to perform schema validation of the configuration files. I don't know if the schemas are available for this specific config. @Nuno - do you know?